# unable to replace space or empty char in phone number

Tags: string, kotlin, replace, space, phone-number

i have been trying to delete an empty space from a phone number string but it doesn't seem to work
this i how i get the number:

```
val indexNumber: Int = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)
val number: String = people.getString(indexNumber)
```

this is what ive tried

```
number.replace("\\s+", "", false)
number.replace("", "", false)
```

also using a regex didn't work i am using the Log to print the numbers this is what i get every time

```
+000 52000000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val number_str: String = "+000 52000   000"
    val number_str_no_blank = number_str.replace(" ", "")
    println(number_str_no_blank)
}
```

Small adjustment needed to use `.replace` correctly to your need. See [doc on strings](http://zetcode.com/kotlin/strings/) for more details.

Comment: works thanks! problem was not returning into a new string